# Swift - IBAction declared in super class is not reflected in subclass in storyboard

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift, ibaction

I have implemented a subclass of UIViewController like this:

```
import UIKit

class LoadImageViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func loadImageAction(sender : AnyObject) {
    }
}
```

Then I implemented subclass of LoadImageViewController like this:

```
class ProfileSnapViewController: LoadImageViewController {
    // an empty implementation
}
```

In storyboard, I assigned class of a UIViewController as ProfileSnapViewController, and then I tried to bind IBAction declared in its superclass to a button, but to my surprise it is not showing the action when I right clicked on the file owner.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: it will appear only if you assign a class `LoadImageViewController ` to viewcontroller

Comment: yeah... but my point was it should have behaved like cocoa classes, where IBOutlets declared in superclasses were automatically visible in storyboard (or in xib).